# Can you get values of the components in the circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, multiplier

I have a mosquito repellent circuit diagram (voltage doubler) with printed values. Can anybody find the actual component value of the capacitors?

[image]

Comment: "105" is 1uF 600v or 1000V    "104" is 0.1uF with a 'X' safety rating for 400V

Comment: Where did the circuit come from (safety is a concern)?

Comment: Where did the circuit come from ?Reliability is a concern

Answer (score 2):

Stay the hell away from that circuit.

You're exposing an accessible metal grid to grid voltage.

With that not being dangerous enough, none of the semiconductors is designed to handle fault currents, there's no protections anywhere in here, so, at some point, an especially large insect, a child's finger, a bird, rain, mist, dirt, or bad luck will destroy this circuit in a chain reaction.

And with destroy I mean cause a fire.

So, no, I will not assist you in finding the component values (that you could've found yourself, to be honest). I will assist in finding a better circuit:

Look for "high voltage low current SMPS". Essentially, a flyback converter would be safer (since it's a) isolated and b) inherently current-limiting, even in a fault condition) and easy to build for your purpose.

But seriously, if this is for a bug zapper:

A 5V USB-or-similar consumer grade supply makes everything safe. Then you'll need some sort of chopper (e.g. a PWM controller IC or simply an oscillator controlling a transistor), and an inductor.

As is taught in the first EE courses, the voltage over an inductor is proportional to the change in current. And your chopper causes a lot of that. Add a high-breakdown-voltage diode to protect the transistor from the inductive kickback, but still allow for insects to be the preferred way to discharge the inductor.

Comment: I recommend an EL inverter. They are safe to use for that bug zapper purpose and cost about $5.

Comment: But it will kill mosquitoes.

Comment: The original circuit will kill small mosquitos, large mosquitos, small rodents, small dogs living in the same house, large dogs, cattle and humans...